# Build Pipeline fails at "Initialize Job" step

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have set up a build pipeline, that builds a solution(windows service), publishes it on a windows server and starts up the service. It runs flawless for the first time.

After that, when I trigger the pipeline, it fails at the ["Initialize Job"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNdAp.png) step and reports that it can't remove some of the files in the Debug folder.

While I know why it can't delete these files(the service is running), I can't figure out a way to stop the service beforehand. I tried running a powershell script as first task like [following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vcbin.png) with script so that it can delete my previous build

```
if (Get-Service "MyService" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {

    net stop MyService
    sc.exe delete MyService

}
```

But it fails even before executing any task from the pipeline.

What's the best way to go about it?

Comment: I still haven't figured it out yet. Like @JukkaK suggested, I'm not going to use the agent's default directory, but how to do that, I don't know yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used these Windows Service Release Tasks in on-prem servers:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jabbera.windows-service-release-tasks

Looking at the attached image, I think might be trying to put stuff that's not supposed to be there in the build pipeline. Instead of trying to install services as a part of the build pipeline (or build stage of multi-stage pipeline), separate deployment tasks to release pipeline (or release stages of multi-stage pipeline). You are now essentially running operations that try to create services within the build agent and you want to run them in the server you are copying the build results into.

Run the release pipeline with deployment group agents so the release is executed at the server you are deploying to, or if that's not possible, run the release pipeline with hosted agents/build server agents, but use WinRM to run the tasks against target server.

Comment: See this for basic concepts: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/?view=azure-devops

Comment: It's a small project and I wanted to get everything done in the build pipeline, that's why I had the script there. But anyway, I now extracted the service starting script to the release pipeline and it fails the same way. I'll give this extension you linked a go.

Comment: Again, doesn't work becaues release pipeline is not even getting triggered. Error occurs before in the "Initialize job" step

Comment: If you created a release pipeline, which kind of stage you are running the powershell in? By default, if you create a new release pipeline with "Empty job" template, you'll get an initial "Stage 1" with and Agent Job. If you are not using Deployment Group Agents, you'll need to use "Run Powershell on Target Machines" -task and provide target server/user/password. Simple Powershell-task is executed within the context of build agent.

Comment: Same thing with the 3rd party tasks referenced before; if you run them with agent job, provide credentials for target server. If you run them with Deployment Group Agent, choose "Target is Deployment Group", and commands are run within the context of deployment group agent installed to the target server.

Comment: For the release pipeline I have set up a Deployment Group and hooked up an agent. But what still happens is, it works for the first time, but than fails, because it can't clean up the target directory from previous build, since the service is still running. I now tried executing a "Run Powershell on Target Machines" in the build pipeline, in order to stop the service before the release pipeline kicks in, but it fails to connect to the server..

Comment: Is your service pointing to the artifact directory of the release definition of the (deployment group) agent you are running the release in? This would explain a lot, since the next release is trying to copy the files of the new artifact on top of the old (which are probably locked as the service runs and all other sorts of mayhem). You'd want to copy the files in you are deploying to some runtime directory (c:\myservice, or whatever you're architecture dictates), create service that points to executable there, and run stop/start commands against that service.

Comment: So i have to manually create an extra service that points to an .exe and starts/stops depening on if the .exe exists or not? Am I following you correctly?

Comment: I'm sure you can script the service creation if you want to, but you don't want the service to point to executable that is located in the agent's work folder structure. You want to deploy (copy, unzip - however you have packaged them) the executable and binaries you have built to somewhere before you create the service. You do not want to point the service to the agent's work folder structure. To understand the agent's work folder structure, see for example this: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/blob/master/docs/jobdirectories.md

Comment: If you look at the errors on the first screenshot you provided, you'll see the "c:\agent\_work\3\a..." -path. That's your build agent you have installed (or perhaps microsoft-hosted agent - dunno which one you are using), it's working directory, third build definition you have run on that particular agent. When you run the build definition again with the same agent, it re-uses the same directory. If you create service that points to the executable within - for example "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_MyArtifact"), you are pointing to agent's working folder.

Comment: Would this screenshot of task group we use with service deployment be of help? https://i.imgur.com/Y59UND1.png What I'm referring to is the copy step here, we source folder points to the build artifact assosicated with the release, and target folder just some folder in local drive where we deploy our apps, services included. The actual service has been created by other means here, but one could probably add a powershell tasks before the start task that would create the service if it doesen't already exist.

Comment: Yes, now it works, and now I get it. Thank you very much!!